# Windows Azure Table Stoarge and Authentication, more than 100 hits per second

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I need solution / recommendation from your expert opinion...

1. We are building an API solution where users will send us a unique code along with  user name and password to get the authentication code and other information...

Challenge We are facing ..

1. How to handle more than 100 request / second?  We currently use mysql but scaling to that level and data storage cost a lot.    Do you think Windows Azure Table Storage is right choice to do lot of selects to authentication and then do update to deduct users credits, who interested in pulling the informatoin from us.....
2. We want to log lot of data. I think windows azure storage will be cheap but how to do the aggregation and analytic?   Do you know any case study / way to import the data back to mysql say daily/hourly partition? any tool or library already available to import Windows Azure storage table data to MySQL Database??
3. How to handle the scenario if someone is try to do lot of abusive request to our server?  Trying to do lot of verification per seconds that are not valid and just result in to many hits on our API ?  How to control that?

Will appreciate any experience of handling high volume request .. We use PHP and MYSQL currently.s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1:Windows Azure Table Storage is designed to handle upwards of 2,000 transactions / second, per partition, and 20,000 transactions / second across the entire storage account, with maximum 10Gbps inbound, 15Gbps outbound bandwidth (see [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/11/02/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx) for complete details). You should have no problem handling 100 tx/sec. And don't forget about entity group transactions, where you can write several entities (within the same partition) in one single transaction.

For #2 (and even #1): Partitioning is very important, to achieve maximum performance. Also remember that, if you need to do complex searching (say, on several different properties), you could end up in a situation where you're doing partition-scans (since the only index you have is partition key + row key). If you plan on doing analytics, it's best to just read this data out, summarize as needed (or denormalize as needed), and write to a database better suited for analysis / drilldown / graphing / etc.

I'd say that #3 should be posted as a separate question, as it falls into the Denial-of-service type of question, which seems unrelated.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed response.. Can you please guide about any example or documents how to aggregate the Azure table storage data and write to MySQL database?  We can do good partition startegy,  to scan hourly partitions.... Any good material for developer how to scan each partition and summarize in PHP program? e.g looping through every 1000 result set and then write those variable to relational database?  What is most efficient way to summarize the data the data and write back to relational data?.

Comment: @EhteshamHaque - I think the aggregation and writing to mysql is out of scope here, as there is it is very open-ended. This is an ETL problem, very specific to your application's domain, based on the type of analysis you wish to do.

Comment: I am interested to know the best way to extract data in bulk?  Can we Extract Partition and save it to file?  Also Can we delete the complete partition in one query?  

Our volumes will be high one day, so i want to implement the best extraction strategy.     Any proven example, any of azure customer implemented this ?  Any already proven library / reference?

For sure i DON NOT want to do row by row processing!